# Does Jax's Counter Strike protect teammates behind him from Twitch's ultimate?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Jax's Counter Strike skill protect teammates behind him from Twitch's ultimate, or does the dodge only apply to himself?

Answer (score 5):

No, Jax's Counter Strike dodge only applies on himself. Teammates behind him take full damage when they are hit by Twitch's ultimate.

You can see this in the following image (taken from [Rift Myths](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUPI-UVLb-E&list=PL0A6DF0EA9708CFC1&index=14&feature=plpp_video&t=1m18s) on youtube)

[image]

(Keep in mind that [Twitch's ultimate is changing](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2347982) and the answer to this question might change or become irrelevant.)

Answer (score 0):

As the answer before says. Jax's counter strike only applies dodge to himself, and every time he dodges he gains more damage when it goes off.